# Using Redis with any Java IDE on a Windows system

Tags: spring-boot, redis, spring-session

I have been finding it hard to configure spring session in spring boot. I have seen a lot of implementation using Redis and using `gem-fire` and `H2 JDBC` has not resulted in anything productive. Can I use Redis with IntelliJ on my Windows system, because I heard it is not supported on Windows?

Comment: Hello welcome to StackOverflow. Please make sure to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Also what do you mean by you heard? A simple google search will give you the answer. I use redis with IntelliJ on my Windows 10 without any issues.

Comment: when i googled it some days ago, i got this "The Redis project does not officially support Windows. However, the Microsoft Open Tech group develops and maintains this Windows port targeting Win64.". so @Shanky my next question is how do i configure my spring session with redis in spring Bot. do u have any examples i can look at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is true that there is no official support for Redis on Windows. From official docs:

> There is no official support for Windows builds, but Microsoft develops and maintains a Win-64 port of Redis.

But as mentioned Microsoft has been maintaining it's [own version](https://github.com/MicrosoftArchive/redis) for over a year now, where you can find [new releases](https://github.com/MicrosoftArchive/redis/releases) and well defined steps for setup on Windows.

**Tutorials:**

There is also a [tutorial](https://github.com/MicrosoftArchive/redis#how-to-build-redis-using-visual-studio) on how to build Redis using `visual studio`. You also should look into the `JetBrains` plugin [iedis](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9228-iedis).

Here is a tutorial for [Redis with Spring](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-redis/), also here's an implementation of [Spring Session with Redis](https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/guides/httpsession.html).